# Event firing with ASP.NET OnTextChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this `asp:TextBox`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="usernameInput" runat="server" 
AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="NameChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

And would like it to post back to my `CodeBehind` in C# whenever the text inside the box changes. I am aware that I need to unfocus the textbox in order to fire the event. I have the feeling `OnTextChanged` should not be in the `asp:TextBox` markup but seeing this done plenty in examples.

```
    public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Adding the event handler manually does not help either.
            usernameInput.TextChanged += new EventHandler(NameChanged);
        }

        public void NameChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Text Changed"); //Having a breakpoint here that has never been reached.

        }
    }
```

So why is it not firing once the box looses focus and it's value has changed?

aspx header:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="~/Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestProject.Index" %>
```

This is the complete form:

```
<form id="signIn" runat="server">
                <p>Username</p>
                <asp:TextBox ID="usernameInput" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="false" OnTextChanged="usernameInput_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                <p>Password</p>
                <asp:TextBox ID="passwordInput" TextMode="Password" runat="server" />
                <p>E-mail</p>
                <asp:TextBox ID="emailInput" TextMode="Email" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" /><br /><br />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="termsInput" runat="server" /><span style="font-size:10px;">I accept the Terms and Conditions.</span><br /><br />
                <asp:Button ID="submit" Text="PLAY" OnClick="ProcessSignIn" runat="server" />
            </form>
```

Current event handler:

```
public void usernameInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Text changed!");
        }
```

With this setup the event handler does fire when the submit button is clicked. It seems like it is acting as if `AutoPostBack` is set to false.

Comment: what do you mean what are you doing wrong.. is it not hitting the `NameChanged` event.. you could do this using javascript and creating a `__DoPostBack` function that forces it to hit that Event.. without having to declare a delegate in the Page_Load event..

Comment: Yeah, needed to change the title which stated it did not fire the method.

Comment: what I have mentioned will work I use it all the time.. in the OnClientTextChanged you can give it the name of any function/event then create the javascript to handle that.. I can post an example of the steps you need to take

Comment: taking a second look your event handler signature look to be incorrect remove the event from the TextBox, then double click inside the textbox area when you are on the `Events` tab next to the properties tab.. and it should create an event called `protected void usernameInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` then paste your Debug.WriteLine code inside that event..

Comment: @MethodMan No results... `<asp:TextBox ID="usernameInput" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="usernameInput_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>` that is what the textbox looks like. And here is the method `protected void usernameInput_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: what does the .aspx header look like can you post it.. I am curious if you have codebehind= or codefile = I would as a last resort do a clean on the project and rebuild the entire solution and try that again.. something is going on in your code.. also one other thing could cause this.. are you running it using IIS or IISExpress.. in project properties what do you have the web server settings setup as .. are you using a port number in the url or not.. this I've ran into a yr ago and it drove me nuts til I figured it out

Comment: It just fired but only when I submitted the form with this button: `<asp:Button ID="submit" Text="PLAY" OnClick="ProcessSignIn" runat="server" />`. But it should fire if the box looses focus and the text has changed right? This is the header: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="~/Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestProject.Index" %>

Comment: @MethodMan And yes I'm using a port number, just running it from visual studio.

Comment: @MethodMan It is like AutoPostBack is set to false. But  it really is set to true.

Comment: set it to true in the designer as well

Comment: @MethodMan It is set to true there and in the code..

Comment: can you show any / all edited code.. also you don't need this if the event was setup correctly by double clicking the event in the designer.. `usernameInput.TextChanged += new EventHandler(NameChanged);` also confirm if the port number in the project matches the port number in the web url when you launch your code.. if it's different I would delete the `cache from the web browser`

Comment: @MethodMan Already commented that out ;). Edited  original question.

Comment: @MethodMan FWIW: I found the answer. Could not have a `asp:Button` with `ID="submit"`. It's probably reserved and conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET

```
usernameInput.Attributes.Add("onchange","javascript:usernameInput_changeHandler()");
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function usernameInput_changeHandler()
{
//client side JS code
}
</script>
```

**Update#1**

If you need to call your C# method, then you will need to defined that as a WebMethod

CS File

```
[WebMethod]
public void FunctionName()
{
    //Your .NET code
}
```

ASPX File

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function usernameInput_changeHandler() 
{
    PageMethods.Name(SuccessFunction, FailureFunction);
}
function SuccessFunction(result) {
    alert(result);
}
function FailureFunction(error) {
    alert(error);
}
</script>

...

<asp:TextBox ID="usernameInput" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="usernameInput_changeHandler();return false;"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: You don't need `javascript:` in event handlers... you can only HAVE javascript in them.  That format is for using javascript in the `href` attribute of an `<a>` element

Comment: But I want to call my C# method. Can I do that from that js event handler?

Comment: If you need to call your C# method, then you will need to defined that as a WebMethod. See my update#1

Answer (score 0):

Move your handler assignment to Page Init.

```
protected void Page_Init()
        {
            usernameInput.TextChanged += new EventHandler(NameChanged);
        }
```

OR 
Add this in the aspx Markup for Your TextBox

```
OnTextChanged="NameChanged"
```

Comment: I have the exact same asox markup you suggested. Very strange it is not working.  Will try to hook up the handler on Page_Init in a couple of minutes but i doubt it helps.  There is something else going on.

Comment: @MethodMan nope, just a basic textbox with the parameters posted in the original question. Anyway, hooking up the Event Handler in `Page_Init()` does not work either.

Comment: what does the .aspx file header look like can you show that first line in the .aspx page..

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct answer but this gave me a serious head injury.

I could not have a `asp:Button` with an `ID` named `submit`, it is probably reserved and throwing an error somewhere. Would love a better explanation.

I started a very basic test implementation and that worked. Luckily when I was rebuilding my code I didn't add the button yet and once I did with the exact same value for `ID` things stopped working. Once I changed the `ID` I started getting call backs when losing focus on the `TextBox`.